# How to address the same item inside a JQM multi-page setup - e.g. checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to determine if a checkbox is checked with jQuery multi page setup, but it always returns "false" unless I mark the item as "checked" per default.

My code looks pretty basic to me:

```
  <script>
    function updateUrls(){
      console.log('test: ' + $('#filter_pic').is(':checked'));
    });
  </script>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter_pic" id="filter_pic" onchange="updateUrls();">with pix
  </form>
```

The reason for this might be, that this code is inside a multi page setup. In fact the code looks similar to this:

```
   <div data-role="page" id="select_dienstleistungen">  
        <div data-role="content"> 
        <script>
        function test() {
          console.log('test: ' + $('#filter_pic').is(':checked'));
        };
   ....
        <form>
           <input type="checkbox" name="filter_pic" id="filter_pic" onchange="updateUrls();">with pix
        </form>
   </div
   <div data-role="page" id="select_jobs">  
        <div data-role="content"> 
        <script>
        function test() { 
    ...
```

How is it possible to address the item inside the pages? All those pages have the same checkbox item as the code is valid for all those different pages.

Comment: It is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/tkkLyd42/

Comment: You should use jQuery event binding, rather than inline `onchange`....

Comment: The jsfiddle is working fine, but on my page I do always get false? How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    $('#filter_pic').change(function() {
        console.log('test: ' + $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
</script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter_pic" id="filter_pic" />with pix
</form>
```

Took out the "onchange".

**Original Post**

Use

```
$('#filter_pic').prop('checked')
```

instead to check the property.

Also, I think it may be a JQuery version problem.  Other people have had this problem as well even though the "is(':checked')" works elsewhere.

Comment: _I am trying to determine if a checkbox is checked with jQuery_

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy This returns true if the checkbox is checked...  Why did you comment?

Comment: Why didn't OP code work? We can suggest him more options but he is asking why his code not giving the expected result.  By the way, I didn't downvote.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy No worries about the down vote, just wondered why you commented.

Comment: .prop() is the best option for working with form "selected" states

Comment: I tried prop as well, but it also returns "false". The version I am using is: jquery-1.12.0.min.js

Comment: @merlin Try my update instead.

Comment: I did, this must be a problem of the multipage setup, as the ID is available multipe time inside the document, but only once inside the page. Looks like an architecture problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function updateUrls(){
      console.log('test: ' + $('#filter_pic').is(':checked'));
    };
  </script>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter_pic" id="filter_pic" onchange="updateUrls();">with pix
  </form>
```

// One extra parenthesis ')' before the ';' semicolon. I have checked by removing this one. And is working fine in my end.

Comment: That must be a typo. Because he's saying the code is printing false all the time. He is not complaining about errors.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo.